# Bootstrap cols are not next to each other

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have simple layout in `HTML` using `Bootstrap` like so

```
<div class='row'>
    <div class="col-6">
     <div class="col-2">
       FOO
     </div>
     <div class="col-4">
       BAR
     </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I expected it be FOO and BAR next to each other, but it is not so? Why? Can someone help me with this?

Here is a [Demo](https://codepen.io/usamarehan/pen/pxYVve)

Comment: read the doc to understand how to correctly nest column : https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/#nesting .. you need row and you also need container as a main wrapper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have nested the columns, please read the [docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/) about bootstrap. To achieve your scope try this code:

```
<div class='row'>
  <div class="col-6">
  </div>
  <div class="col-2">
    FOO
  </div>
  <div class="col-4">
    BAR
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The grid system has a full size of 12. Hence the columns could have combination of any one of below:

[image: Grid system]

Comment: He nested the columns in a wrong way, this is why the grid layout didn't work. Moreover the sum of the column he used is 12.

Comment: @user9741470 Check his code in the pen link he mentioned.

Comment: He posted the code, so I assume the pen linked has the same code. If not I assume this was a mistake of the user

Comment: @user9741470 I don't assume. I just go by facts. The code is not the same.

Comment: He need to modify the code to reflect the linked one.

Comment: Well that doesn't have anything to do with my answer :) I gave generic answer.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with having the sum of the columns exceed 12, they'll just [wrap to a new row](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/#column-wrapping). That's not causing the problem that the OP has.